# Why is BFMatcher::match() not symmetric in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, match

Matching binary descriptors from an image A to a set of images B*, I happened to try inverting the "train" and the "query" images for the following function:

```
cv::BFMatcher matcher;
matcher.match(queryDescriptors, trainDescriptors, matches);
```

First point is that the function is not symmetric, i.e. match(trainDescriptors, queryDescriptors, matches) will not give the same number of matches.

Second is that if I use A as the query image, and B* as the train images (in a for-loop), then I always get the same number of matches from A to the images of B* (for instance, if A -> B1 has 155 matches, then A -> Bx all have 155 matches).

But if I do the opposite (i.e. using B* as the query images and A as the train image), then the number of matches is different each time (which seems more logical to me).

**Intuitively, I would say that the matches between A and Bx should be the same as the matches between Bx and A, but it is apparently not the case. Why is that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BFMatcher::match() actually returns, for each descriptor of the query image, the best match to the train image. From this, we can conclude that:

- The number of matches is always the number of descriptors of the query image
- This is asymmetric: assuming the best match for a descriptor Ax is Bz, and that the best match for a descriptor Ay is Bz (i.e. two descriptors on A are matched to the same descriptor in B), then we clearly see that the best match for Bz is either Ax or Ay, but not both.

Assuming that a geometry validation is done afterwards (e.g. using homography), then it might be possible that it is better to choose the query image and the train image in such a way that the number of matches is maximized.